# How to include definitely typed files in an Angular2 angular-cli based project

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, definitelytyped

What is the best practice for this scenario:

I have created an Angular2 project using `angular-cli` (i.e. using `ng new`)

I want to include TypeScript types from [definitely typed](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped)

For example, should I use [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) to install the types? How do I make sure the types are included in the `ng build`?

If you answer is that I should hack the `webpack` settings somehow, please include how I would do that, since I only have the `angular-cli.json` file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Angular-cli uses typescript 2.0, you just need to search for the typings on npm, say you want jquery types, just install them:

```
npm install --save @types/jquery
```

And that's it. More info [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#3rd-party-library-installation)

Comment: That works for libraries which have their typings published on npm only. Some smaller libraries only have an older DefinitelyTyped typings file. You can use typings to install that using `typings install dt~my-library-name --global`, but angular-cli will not pick it up, unfortunately

Comment: How does one refer to these new types within an Angular component, say? (FYI - your "more info here" link is broken).