# VsCode, @angular/cli, and Bing Maps v8 typings

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, bing-maps, typescript-typings

For the life of me I can't figure out how to get everything working together properly. Here's my current versioning setup:

- VsCode v1.13.1
- node v6.9.1
- npm v5.1.0
- @angular/cli v1.2.0
- @angular v4.0.0
- bingmaps v1.0.14
- typescript v2.4.1
- typings v2.1.1

From what I gather, I should just be able to run `npm install --save bingmaps` and everything should magically work.

I have tried all sorts of combinations of npm/typings dev/local/global installs and imports/declarations/etc./etc. but nothing seems to get it working.

Given a basic, completely empty boilerplate app (`ng new testproject`) and using VsCode as the IDE:

How does one get bing maps **v8** working nicely as part of the project? Note: Typings and compilation, specifically, not worrying about how to get the map working/showing/etc as that isn't the issue.

I would very much like to stop seeing the `Cannot find name 'Microsoft'` compilation error and get on with some actual development on it.

Thank you.

Edit:

This is technically a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40280707/how-to-include-definitely-typed-files-in-an-angular2-angular-cli-based-project) question, I guess, though @types/bingmaps is v7, not v8. Doing a basic `npm install --save bingmaps` seems like it works (and should, from what I understand). I actually get intellisense and everything seems right with the world. (At least it did once, I can't seem to repeat that).

... Until I attempt to run it (`ng serve -o`).

After failing to run (well, compile, even), I *then* have my `Microsoft` (e.g. `let map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(...)`) gain the ever loved red squiggly underline, as well as having the compilation error thrown in my face:

`ERROR in ...../src/app/app.component.ts (12, 21): Cannot find name 'Microsoft'.`

What is going on?

Edit 2:

Throwing in `declare var Microsoft: any;` into `typings.d.ts` gets rid of the compilation errors, but still no intellisense.

Edit 3:

So, fun times. `declare var Microsoft: any;` added to the `typings.d.ts` solves the compilation (as mentioned).

But: If I throw in a `/// <reference ... />` to the typings in there as well, compilation breaks. However, I get the intellisense.

Oddly, if I start serving (`ng serve -o`), without the `/// <reference ... />` (so compilation is fine) and *then* add in the ref while it's running, I get to have it running and get intellisense. Should I stop serving, of course, I need to remove the ref, start serving, and can then put it back.

I'm not sure why it seems these things are mutually exclusive to being in there together.

Edit 4:

As I spiral into madness, `declare var Microsoft: any;` in the `typings.d.ts` solves compilation issues in the *component*. However, any mention of `Microsoft` in another file (i.e. my *service*) and it suddenly has no idea what I'm talking about.

If anyone has any ideas, you can find me weeping softly into my pillow.

Edit 5:

For crying out loud. Ok, currently I have `declare var Microsoft: any` in my `typings.d.ts` which seems to be taking care of any mentions of `Microsoft` in my component.ts, while I have a `/// <reference path="..." />` in my service.ts to stop *that* from throwing up at the mere mention of `Microsoft`...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
npm install --save @types/bingmaps
```

Then in your angular 4 service/module/whatever

```
import { } from '@types/bingmaps';

declare var Microsoft: any;
```

Then you will be able to use the types like this

```
const loc = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(lat, lng);
```

But the Bingmaps script will not be loaded by this, just the types from DefinitelyTyped. So either add a script tag in the head of your index.html to load the bingmaps js file or load it dynamically in your typescript

Comment: The @types are for v7, whereas I'm working with v8. I'm currently living with the rather odd setup from my 5th edit. It works, which will have to be good enough for now.